# How to pass argparse arguments to another python program?

Tags: python, argparse

I am tying a script which will pass argparse arguments to another python

1st script : **t.py**

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname",  help="first name")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-lname","--lname", help="last name")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

fname = commandLineArguments.fname
lname = commandLineArguments.lname

print "%s\n%s" %(fname,lname)

os.system("python test1.py")
```

code for test1.py is bellow

```
import argparse
import os

print "test abc"
```

I want to pass **lname** and **fname** values to **test1.py** .is their their any way to do that.

in the above code if I ran

```
python t.py -fname ms lname = dhoni
```

then the output is

```
ms
dhoni
test abc
```

But I want the output to be like bellow

```
ms
dhoni
ms
dhoni
```

Comment: is there any reason why you are not importing t.py in test1.py?  that way you could get access to the argparse values

Comment: I don't know how to import t.py in in test1.py .is their any to import.it will be very helpful for me if I can import t.py directly in test1.py.

Comment: I want to make a command like bellow ..`python test1.py --lname=ms -fname=dhoni` the argments will directly come from argparse.is is possible to do ? that will solve my problem. I will receive those value using argparse again.

Comment: if you want to do `python test1.py --lname=ms -fname=dhoni` then you can  do as [Arthur Vaïsse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29747510/2032074) says.  if you want to try the import way, check out my answer below

Comment: This really isn't an `argparse` issue, but rather `how do you issue a system call that includes arguments?`.  The use of `argparse` in `t1` is independent of its use (or not) in `test1`.

Comment: when I am printing the value of `commandLineArguments`, i am getting `Namespace(fname='ms', lname='dhoni')` as a output. is their any way to change that part into `--lname=ms -fname=dhoni` or `-lname=ms -fname=dhoni` .

Comment: @hpaulj - thanks for you valuable reply. I want to grab all the argument parameter which user gives. for example if user tried `python t.py -fname=ms ` so I want to grab `-fname=ms` part only .So the I can pass the arguments to `test1.py` easily in the same way...

Comment: Does `t.py` need to parse the arguments, or just pass them on to `test1.py` (unchanged)?  Sometimes one module parses some of the arguments, and pass the `REMAINDER` (that it doesn't handle) to another module.

Comment: I need to u pass them in unchanged condition. Finally I got the idea by the discussion. thanks for the conversation and stack overflow is great .

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `test1.py`:

```
from sys import argv
print "%s\n%s" % (argv[1], argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum I don't understand why you are trying to do that, but you really already have all that is required to achieve this task :

First python script (I call it sof.py):

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname",  help="first name")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-lname","--lname", help="last name")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

fname = commandLineArguments.fname
lname = commandLineArguments.lname

print("%s\n%s" %(fname,lname))
command = "python sof2.py {arg1} {arg2}".format(arg1=fname, arg2=lname)
os.system(command)
```

Second python scrit (sof2.py here)

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("fname")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("lname")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

fname = commandLineArguments.fname
lname = commandLineArguments.lname

print "%s\n%s" %(fname,lname)
```

This give me the following execution :

```
python3 sof.py -fname foo -lname bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

NB : I use python3 but if you have to use python2 this code is still correct, just remove `(` and `)` around the `print`

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply .If I changed the command line little bit than what will be the out put .change mean If i tried **python sof.py -lname bar -fname foo**

Comment: It will not work. I defined `fname` and `lname` as positional arguments in the second script. If the argparse argument start with a `-` character it become an optional argument and have to be inputed as such. So as the argument `-foo` and `-bar` are optional when calling script you have to write `script -bar barvalue -foo foovalue` but if you define an argument without a `-` at start, then it become a positional parameter. So with `foo` and `bar` the call become : `script foovalue barvalue`. You can't call `fname` and `lname` with a `-` you have to add it to the argparse parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify test1.py to include t.py and directly access the argparse variables.

test1.py

```
import t.py
print t.fname, t.lname
```

Comment: Your answer makes most sense, unless that `os.system("python test1.py")` run bit is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Change your test1.py to:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

print sys.argv
print "test abc"
```

And call your `test1.py` from `t.py` as:

```
os.system("python test1.py vv gg hh")
```

Now your args `vv gg hh` are available in `test1.py`.